# PHP MySQL Item Count Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a useraccount table that "contains" tag with current date:

```
$date=date("m/d/y", time());

$sql="SELECT 
user , 
id ,
tag,
COUNT(user)
from useraccount
where 'tag' LIKE '%$date%'";
```

Example table:

```
user1, id1, date1
user2, id2, date1
user1, id3, date1
user2, id4, date1
user2, id5, date1
```

This should return a table:

```
 user1, 2
 user2, 3
```

I need to create a new query that contains number of counts of tag that contain current date on the tag for that particular user.  Tag is contain current date with other random number on it.

I need help in SQL logic to generate a query or new table that contains the item count.

Comment: So is the query above your attempt? It is unclear what that query is for.  I notice that it has a single quoted string `'tag'` where you need to use an unquoted `tag` or backquoted `\`tag\``

Comment: `"SELECT user, count(1) FROM useraccount WHERE tag LIKE '%$data%' GROUP BY user"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
$date=date("m/d/y", time());

$sql="SELECT 
user, 
id,
tag,
COUNT(user)
FROM useraccount
WHERE `tag` LIKE '%$date%'
GROUP BY user";
```

When using GROUP BY, you can do queries like:

```
mysql> SELECT student.student_name,COUNT(*)
    ->        FROM student,course
    ->        WHERE student.student_id=course.student_id
    ->        GROUP BY student_name;
```

Which will give you a count of how many `student_name` are the same and will only show the `student_name` once(distinct).

```
 +--------------+----------+
 | student_name | count(*) |
 +--------------+----------+
 |     John Doe |       20 |
 +--------------+----------+
```